# Amendments to code to run on all rows

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following coding for a set of data on an excel spreadsheet:

```
    Sub DemoMutual2()
Dim URL As String
Dim ieDoc As Object, dObj As Object
Dim cel As Range

    URL = Range("G2").Value
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate URL

        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Set ieDoc = .Document
        Set dObj = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("_50f3")
        [K2].Value = Split(ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("_50f3")(0).innerText, " ")(0)
        For i = 0 To dObj.Length - 1
            If InStr(1, dObj(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText, "since") Then
                [M2].Value = Trim(Split(dObj(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText, "since")(1))
            End If
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    Set ieDoc = Nothing
    Set dObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

At present this only works on one row, based on the URL in cell G2. What I want this code to do is run for all of the URLs in column G (G2,G3,G4 etc) and return the required results in the cells specified in the code (K2, K3, K4 etc and M2, M3, M4 etc).

So to search URL in G2 and return results in K2 and M2
then G3, results in K3 and M3 and so on.

At present this works perfectly for the one row, but I am struggling to change it so I can do it for multiple rows.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have specific rows to run it on, or do you want it to run from `G2` until the last cell in column G?

Comment: Hi BruceWayne, thanks for your reply. I would like it to run until the last cell in column G as the amount of data in the worksheet would vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does this work?

```
Sub DemoMutual2()
Dim URL     As String
Dim ieDoc As Object, dObj As Object
Dim cel     As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, iRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

For iRow = 2 To lastRow
    URL = Range("G" & iRow).Value
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate URL

        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Set ieDoc = .Document
        Set dObj = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("_50f3")
        Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Split(ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("_50f3")(0).innerText, " ")(0)
        For i = 0 To dObj.Length - 1
            If InStr(1, dObj(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText, "since") Then
                Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Trim(Split(dObj(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText, "since")(1))
            End If
        Next i
        .Quit
    End With
    Set ieDoc = Nothing
    Set dObj = Nothing
Next iRow

End Sub
```

Note: It may be better to move the `IE.Quit` and `Set ieDoc = Nothing` lines to outside the whole loop for performance, but this should work if you don't have too many rows.

Comment: Amazing, that is perfect! Thanks BruceWayne, it turns out that not all heroes wear capes...or do they...